# How do I send a new contact to the ios contacts app?

Tags: iphone, contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add a contact from within an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395057/how-to-add-a-contact-from-within-an-app)

In our app, we want to have an 'add contact' button, which launches the contacts app with a prepopulated new contact.  Is that possible, and if so how?  I'd like to avoid having to design our own 'new contact' form.

Answer (score 4):

See [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395057/how-to-add-a-contact-from-within-an-app) for your answer.

Basically you need to use ABNewPersonViewController.

Answer (score 4):

Instantiate a `ABNewPersonViewController` and present it modally. You can optionally create a `ABRecordRef` containing the values you want to be prepopulated and assign it to the controller's `displayedPerson` property.